# Error 1064 al crear un disparador Before Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Al crear un disparador Before Insert me genera un error 1064 de sintaxis, por más que reviso el código no localizo qué pasa:

```
SELECT Menus.Color INTO @col FROM Menus WHERE Menus.id = NEW.Menus_id;

SET NEW.Color = @col;
```

He probado la primera línea y funciona. La segunda también cambiando @col por "algo".

Lo hago desde phpMyAdmin por lo que no tengo que agregar delimitadores, creo.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene esto: `SET NEW.Color = @col;`?

Comment: Pues sería asignar a Color el valor obtenido de la tabla Menus con la propiedad @col
Así lo he visto en varios ejemplos, y otros disparadores que tengo.

Comment: De todos modos no veo qué sentido tiene hacer eso.